# getting crash while Accessing relationship objects One to One coredata/stackmob

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, entity-relationship, stackmob

I have 2 tables Assets and Rewards there are related 
Assets<---->Rewards, with relationshipname assetrewards, when i am trying to access the rewards table field likewise

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Assets"]; 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"assetsId == %@",str]; 
[request setPredicate:predicate]; 
[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request onSuccess:^(NSArray *assetsArr) { 
for (Assets *assets in assetsArr) { 
NSLog(@"assets %@",[assets valueForKey:@"assetrewards.rewardsId"]); 
}
} onFailure:^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error fetching: %@", error);

    }];
```

then i am getting a crash report saying

```
:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Assets 0x9fb9380> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Assets is not key value coding-compliant for the key "assetrewards.rewardsId".'
```

but when i am checking like wise

```
NSLog(@"assets %@",[assets valueForKey:@"assetrewards"]);
```

i am getting output like this :

```
assets <Rewards: 0xad8a4f0> (entity: Rewards; id: 0x9fe4bf0 <x-coredata://B2D33481-2AF2-4C6D-9428-33BDCF653881-15578-00004A2B32ACC29E/Rewards/pc05848de529d4cbab6eb4475a5f9f591> ; data: <fault>)
```

I want access the all the values of the rewards fields with the relationship/ or for that particular asset as there is a reward related i want to get the details of the Rewards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `valueForKey:` on a multi-step key path like `assetrewards.rewardsId`. You have to use `valueForKeyPath:`. As written, the code is looking for a key named `assetrewards.rewardsId`, **not** a key named `assetrewards` that leads to an object with a key named `rewardsId`.

Comment: Thank you.. its great it worked for me, earlier i had done this but nvr knew this small logic... @Tom.